# GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault silent timeout

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am running a .NET application inside a docker container on a Compute Instance. I'm trying to get my app to make a call out to another Compute Instance. I am generating my token from a `credentials.json` file saved in the container with the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing to it.

The issue I am having is my code is hitting `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()`, timing out, and not throwing any errors, thus not giving any indication of what is causing the timeout.

When running the code on my local machine, I ran into a similar issue but was able to get around it by placing breakpoints inside the decompiled `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2` library and see what the issues were (this helped me solve some credentials file issues). However I'm unable to do this when the code is inside the docker container so am not able to diagnose the issue.

This is a slimmed down version of my code:

```cs
public class TextToVectorService : ITextToVectorService
{
  private readonly string audience = "<DESTINATION_PRIVATE_CLOUDRUN_URL>";  // e.g. "https://text-to-vector-fs4g3759-ts.a.run.app"
  private readonly IMyLogger _logger;
  private readonly Lazy<Task<OidcToken>> _token;
  // ...

  public TextToVectorService(IMyLogger logger) {
    _logger = logger;
    _token = new Lazy<Task<OidcToken>>(async () => {
      try {
        _logger.LogMessage("Beginning token generation");
        var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(); // <--- Times out here

        _logger.LogMessage("Got credential");
        var tokenOptions = OidcTokenOptions.FromTargetAudience(audience)
                                           .WithTokenFormat(OidcTokenFormat.Standard);
        
        _logger.LogMessage($"Got credential type {credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetType().Name}");
        var oidcToken = await credential.GetOidcTokenAsync(tokenOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        return oidcToken;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.LogError(e);
        throw;
      }
    });
  }

  public async Task<IEnumerable<float>> EncodeText(string text)
  {
    _logger.LogMessage("Very start of Service call");
    // Set up API call...

    try {
      _logger.LogMessage("Getting auth");
      var authHeader = await GenerateAuthHeader();
      
      _logger.LogMessage("Starting to make API call"); // Never gets to here
      // Make API Call, return result...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.LogError(e);
        return Array.Empty<float>();
    }
  }

  private async Task<AuthenticationHeaderValue> GenerateAuthHeader()
  {
    var tokenValue = await _token.Value;
    var token = await tokenValue.GetAccessTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // Never gets to here
    _logger.LogMessage($"Got token: {token}");
    return new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
  }
}
```

and these are the log messages I'm seeing:

```
2023-04-19T14:08:16.441   message         Very start of Service call
2023-04-19T14:08:16.441   message         Getting auth
2023-04-19T14:08:16.441   message         Beginning token generation
```

No other logs are entered, no errors are thrown, and then my request times out.

How can I get more information about what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

> I am generating my token from a credentials.json file saved in the container with the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable pointing to it.

Instead of using a service account key, it's better to [attach the service account to the VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes). `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault` can then fetch the access token and/or ID token from the VM's metadata server and you avoid the [risks of using service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-managing-service-account-keys).

> The issue I am having is my code is hitting GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(), timing out, and not throwing any errors, thus not giving any indication of what is causing the timeout.

When you use a service account key, the library makes a call to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` to authenticate and obtain a token. For that call to work, your VM must have an external IP address, be in a subnet that [allows Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access), or must have NAT-ed/proxied egress access. If none of that is the case, this outbound call fails or (eventually) times out, and I suspect that's what might be happening here.

If you attach the service account to the VM instance, these outbound calls become unnecessary, so I figure that might be the best route to take.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes Passing, I'll look into this and see how I get on